# How do I use a variable as an array index in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, openpyxl

I have 2 classes, `Product` and `Transaction`.
Each `Product` object represents a product that is sold, and each `Transaction` object represents how much of that product was sold.

I am making an array of `Product` objects called `product_list` and an array of `Transaction` objects called `transaction_list`. Both classes have an attribute called `ProductID`, which is a string of some characters like "ABCDE". What I need to do is add data from each `Transaction` object to attributes of the `Product` objects.

Currently, I have an attribute in the `Transaction` object called `product_list_index` that would be the same as the index of the `Product` object in the `product_list` array that has the same `ProductID` as the given `Transaction` object.

My approach was going to be to iterate through every transaction in the array, and set the `product_list_index` of each `Transaction` object to the index of whichever `Product` object had the matching `ProductID` attribute.  So when I add data to the  `Product` object, it would be like this:

`x = 1`(this would be data from the transaction)

`product_list[product_list_index].total_gallons_sold_of_this_product += x`

Is there a better way to link the objects together based on a variable instead of iterating through every one to find the correct index?

Here is a minimum example of my code (there's a lot cut out to make it eaiser to read):

```
class Product:
   def __init__ (self, productID)
      self.brandName = ""
      self.productID = str(productID)
      self.total_gallons_sold_of_this_product = 0
      self.total_gallons_sold_to_retailers = 0
      self.total_gallons_sold_to_customers = 0

class Transaction:
   def __init__ (self, productID)
      self.productID = str(productID)
      self.total_gallons_for_this_sale = 0  # gets input from generate_transaction_list function
      self.is_retailer_sale = 0  # boolean, if it's not a retailer sale then it's a customer sale

def generate_transaction_list():  # Makes an array of Transaction objects from an excel spreadsheet, uses a pandas dataframe, returns the array
...
def generate_product_list():  # Makes an array of the different products based on an excel spreadsheet, returns the array
...

array_transaction_data = generate_transaction_list()
product_list = generate_product_list()
```

Comment: can you please provide the code, that you have so far

Comment: Please include a [mre]! We can understand your problem better if you include code!

Comment: I added some code based on what my script looks like, only the parts related to what I need to do.  Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Are you looking for dictionaries?

Comment: @MadPhysicist looks like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is an ideal use-case for a dictionary. A dictionary is a lot like an array, but instead of using sequential numbers `0, 1, 2...` as keys (which would be an array) you can use arbitrary strings. So you can have, for example,

```py
products = {
    '1a1a': MyDrillObject,
    '2b2b': MyScrewsProduct,
    'fffee': MyTowelProduct
}
```

and then to retrieve a specific object representing a product you can do, for example,

```py
drill_obj = products['1a1a']
```

And this lookup is efficient, it doesn't iterate through all the keys in the dictionary.

So to solve your problem, you could do away with your product list index and instead use the `ProductID` as the dictionary key directly.

This would do simplify the preprocessing step down to just adding all the products to the product dictionary:

```py
product_dict = {p.ProductID: p for p in products}
```

and then when processing transactions, you can use the productID directly:

```py
product_dict[transaction.ProductID].total_gallons_sold_of_this_product += x
```

Comment: This solution was easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Let `Transaction` have a `Product` instance instead `productId`:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, product):
        self.product = product
```

Then you can:

```
def generate_product_list():
    productId2Product = {}
    ...  # reading from file
        productId2Product[productId] = Product(productId)
    return productId2Product


def generate_transaction_list(productId2Product):
    transaction_list = []
    ...  # reading from file
        transaction_list.append(Product(productId2Product[productId]))
    return transaction_list
     

productId2Product = generate_product_list()

array_transaction_data = generate_transaction_list(productId2Product)

array_transaction_data[i].product.total_gallons_sold_of_this_product += x
```

Comment: I agree, implement as a list if the transactions have multiple products. Another implementation would be to give every sold product a reference to a transaction using this same method or a transaction_id.

Comment: How would I make that point to the correct `Product` object in the `product_list` array?

Comment: Do you mean how do you determine what kind of `Product` your are dealing with or how to find a specific `Product`?

Comment: for example, there are 3 different products that would each get their own object in the array.  the `Transaction` object needs to add data to the `Product` object that has the same `ProductID`.

Comment: @svenfulen Edited again to use dictionary to get `Product` instances. You may get an idea?